# SQL Server - Stop user from making secondary account without a main account

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I've been trying to get my code to work but it isn't functioning as intended, basically @NAME is what the user inputs when trying to create a new user, the @Tmpname is the name without any numbers, as there are original accounts (John Smith) and secondary accounts (John Smith 2, John Smith 3, John Smith 4 and so on).

I want @Name to **IS NULL** if there is no original user and they're treating to create a secondary account. The script will only fire if @Name has a number in it, so original accounts being made will not be effected by this search

Example of what is intended,

User attempts to create 'John Smith 2', there is no 'John Smith' so it NULLs @Name (and errors the script)

Currently it will null out @Name even if there is an existing user, I don't want this,

Example of what it does currently
User attempts to create 'John Smith 2', there **is a** 'John Smith', it nulls @Name and errors the script

```
SELECT @NAME = --If user is attempting to make a secondary account without an original account
CASE
    WHEN @TmpName = name
THEN @Name
ELSE NULL
END
FROM t_employee
WHERE @NAME LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

This is my first time on this platform, so please let me know if you require any more information, the error definitely lies within this piece of code and not elsewhere in my script as commenting it out resolves any errors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a read of the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), this sort of question will benefit from a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Are you making an enormous assumption about names here? And notice that your query can select MANY rows but you assign a scalar value from it. This is a good example of a bad habit. If you expect and require a single value, use the form `set @x = (select ...);` which will throw an error when multiple rows are selected.

Comment: And BTW names are not unique - even in relatively small populations. I worked in a location with about 150 people with 2 having the same name (in an organization having tens of thousands of employees). Be VERY careful what you assume and how you design what seems like something that should be secure and perhaps very sensitive (PII).

Comment: @SMor Thanks for your advice, I'm still quite new to SQL. :)

Comment: @SMor What advice would you have to get past the unique name problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood what you're trying to do, something like this should work:

```
If @Name Like '%[0-9]%' And Not Exists
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM t_employee
    WHERE name = @TmpName
)
BEGIN
    SET @Name = NULL;
END;
```

Comment: That seems to work, thank you Richard!